# How to fix unknown icons on Taskbar on Windows 11

Tags: windows, taskbar, icons, windows-11

The Windows 11 does not recognize some icons on taskbar. As we can see in the pic below I have the Google Chrome and I don't know what to do to fix it. When I pin it on the taskbar, sometimes it recognizes but when I unpin it, it just lost and never work for opened programs. It also happen sometimes with other programs like Visual Studio Code (Microsoft).

It adds confusion when I have lots of programs open, forcing me to hover over each window preview with the mouse and verify it is the program I am looking for.

Researching about it, I found some suggestions on changing a random the Windows Registry entry, and I tried, but after one day, the problem came back.

How can I fix the icons?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The Windows 11 does not recognize some icons on taskbar. As we can see
> in the pic bellow I have the Google Chrome and I don't know what to do
> to fix it. When I pin it on the taskbar, sometimes it recognizes but
> when I unpin it, it just lost and never work for opened programs.

Windows 11 works entirely differently than Windows 10 in terms of Task Bar and Launcher (Start Menu) and Windows 10 behaviour cannot natively be retrofitted to Windows 11, at least not at this point. Who knows what the future holds.

> The Windows 11 does not recognize some icons on taskbar

So far as I know, in a properly operating Windows 11 System, all icons related to installed apps are known. It is possible there is a an installation error or other error, but if all is working all icons are known.

You can try replacing the icon on the task bar to see if that fixes the issue. Unpin, restart, Pin and check.

On my Windows 11 Production machine (and Insider for that matter), all icons that I put on the Task Bar are recognized. There are no icons that do not function.

All that you need is in Windows 11 and I have tried to portray some snap shots showing how to use Windows 11.

To see what the icon is requires hovering over it and there are different ways the icon will appear upon hovering.

Simple icons show the app label. For example, right now my File Explorer is closed and I just see File Explorer when I hover.

[image: File Explorer]

If the app is active (Chromium Edge is active right now), then I see a Thumbnail of the app. (Similar to what you saw for Chrome).

[image: Active App]

> when I unpin it, it just lost and never work for opened programs

I do not think Apps are lost forever. If you unpin the App, then it remains in the Launcher (Start Menu).  I have apps that are not pinned to the Task Bar - I just find them in the launcher (which I have set a little bit like the Windows 10 Start Menu).

Open Start and if the icon you want is not there, click on All Apps. Your installed app will surely be there.

[image: Start Menu]

You can also put Apps on the actual Start Menu (Launcher) and arrange most used apps to the main Launcher Screen. I use this all the time. Start, select app.

I have put apps not on my desktop but frequently used here.

[image: Launcher]

.

*So overall Windows 11 is just a very different way of working and all that you installed is easily available to you - just in a different way.*

Comment: Helpful in terms of explaining Windows 11 (+1), but does not provide an actual fix for the question (-1). Suggest noting /removing personal document names in final screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: There is no fix for properly operating icons - they just show in different ways. Errors would have to be fixed. I updated the final screen shot. Many thanks.

Comment: In Windows 10 I sometimes get stuck icons when a program updates. I usuaully have to unpin the app from taskbar, then the icon shows right, and pin it again.

Comment: That is there "error " part of my post. I usually don't see stuck icons, but as you note, replacing on the task bar works. I clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks @John! I was thinking there was an icon cache or such, or one can manually re-set the icon in properties, but I had not dug into that further.

Comment: +1 from me too. Do note, I usually open the app first on the taskbar, then unpin from there, icon resets on the taskbar to the correct one, then pin it from the taskbar again to fix it. :) That said, I am on Win 10, not 11. So may have changed on 11.

Comment: Thanks -  I have not seen a way in Icon Cache to fix icons. I remake the task bar like LPChip does and that works.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to run the application and un-pin it from the taskbar while running. The icon then appeared immediately and stayed there after re-pinning to the taskbar.

Comment: thank you! It did the trick for me too :)

Comment: That worked for PyCharm but not for Chrome and a bunch of others. This is a total defect by Microsoft. Inexplicable how they could roll out such garbage.

Comment: Did not work for any of my apps with missing icons.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to fix unknown icon on windows 11

1. Right click on the unknown icon
2. Right click on the app name
3. Click on "Properties"
4. Click on "Change Icon..." button
5. Select the proper icon from the list
6. Click "OK"
7. Click "Apply" --> "OK"

Now close and re-open the app.

Comment: I have a different problem, also related to icons not showing in W11: in my case, I'd like Tray Status's numlock icon to show, but I can't even find it in Taskbar settings... It's just not there, as in, not proposed at all. Same with CoreTemp. I tried to delete the icon caches in AppData, but I can't. I get an error message stating that the files in question are in use by Explorer (duh), and I just can't delete them, not even mark them for deletion at next startup. I bought this (new, Asus) laptop with W11 preinstalled, and how I regret it now...

Comment: @Didier If it is a different problem, then ask as a new question(add some screenshots too). Then maybe someone can help you.

Comment: My problem is related to this one in the sense that Windows 11 doesn't allow me to properly manage how my application icons are displayed in the notification area either, but it's a moot point, because since I posted that comment, I've reinstalled Windows 10 Pro, and the issue is gone (as I knew it would). For me, this simply demonstrates how unready for public consumption Windows 11 still is, two years after its release, and what a poor job at addressing simple issues Microsoft is doing.

Comment: What fixed the problem for me was to... go back to Windows 10... :-) No more issues of any kind, except for a strange problem with file sharing and RDP, but there's already a live topic on the subject elsewhere. Windows 11 is not for everyone. I thought I could get used to its peculiarities for the sake of novelty, but I can't. Good luck to the OP with his/her own issues.

Answer (score 1):

Pinning/Unpinning did not work for me. I was able to fix this issue by deleting the corresponding entry in

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\ImplicitAppShortcuts\<id>
```

*(*Really* trying not to comment about this being in an `Internet Explorer` folder...)*

After forced restart of `Explorer.exe`, the icon got refreshed automatically. Restarting explorer (or rebooting I guess) is *required*.

You can find this location by yourself by right-clicking the application icon in the task-bar, then right-clicking on the application name, then selecting properties, then find that location in the "General" tab:

[image: right-click the application icon in the task-bar, right-click the application name, click properties]
[image: select general tab and copy the path from the location field]

Comment: This didn't work for UWP apps (snipping tool, photos, windows security) or other apps like Microsoft ToDo because there's no "Properties" to select after right-clicking the app name. I had two <id> folders but neither had entries that corresponded to my missing icons:-(

Comment: It's so usefull to me to know the exact folder:
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar

So I edited icon in the properties then restart explorer.exe

Thanks a lot =]